# Using Frequency formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know the frequency is not correct because there cannot be 199 5's if there are 199 numbers total, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I added a pic that shows the limits I am putting in the for the formula. Its like its adding each frequency to the one before it maybe?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6P5U.png]

Comment: One thing I can see, is that you have got a relative data array, that will increase when you drag it down. Furthermore, it's unclear what your goal is. Like, @cybernetic.nomad says, please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems going on.  As JvdV commented, the relative range references become a changing value as you drag the formula down.  That's a problem because you shouldn't drag the formula (see below); you don't actually need absolute addressing when you apply it correctly.  You're also using the wrong syntax, and the combination of the two problems is producing the incorrect counts.

The correct syntax is `FREQUENCY(data_array,bins_array)`.  You're defining just one bin rather than the array.  The assigned bin value is the count of everything that is greater than the last bin threshold and less than or equal to the current bin threshold.  At the last bin, with no previous bin (since the range is one cell), all of the data is less than or equal to the bin threshold, so it gets the entire count.

Note that this is an array formula.  The way to use it in your case would be to highlight the output range (C2:C6), and enter:

```
=FREQUENCY(A1:A199,B2:B6)
```

Then confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Excel will add curly braces and fill the output range from that one formula.

See https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-frequency-function.

Comment: Yes! Plus it's an array formula. Confirmed through Ctrl+Shift+Enter